# SQL function for combining columns into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a SQL function that combines x number of columns and y number of rows into 1 column with the rows comma seperated and sorted alphabetically.

Example

```
1          2           3         4
A          B           C         D
E          F           G         H
I          J           K         L
```

Should turn into

```
1
A,B,C,D
E,F,G,H
I,J,K,L
```

I tried searching but I could not find any solution that didn't include the columns being hardcoded in.

Comment: Why is the "columns being hardcoded in" a problem?

Comment: It is a problem because I have many columns and need to do this several times. So writing 100+ columns into the funciton every time is no fun :)

Comment: So use SQL to generate SQL. You can't use dynamic SQL in a function but you can still do a query against `sys.columns` at design time to generate the desired SQL. It will be better performing than roundtripping through XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not clear why you want to avoid hardcoding columns but this works ([based on idea here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/Mw8pdoA0OSs)).

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(concatenated, 2, 0 + 0x7FFFFFFF)
FROM   YourTable C
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT ',' + t.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(128)')
                    FROM   (SELECT (SELECT C.*
                                    FOR XML RAW, TYPE) AS x)v
                           CROSS APPLY v.x.nodes('row/@*') AS t(c)
                    ORDER  BY t.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(128)')
                    FOR XML PATH('')) CA(concatenated)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7be162/1)

To also concatenate across rows you could use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(concatenated, 2, 0 + 0x7FFFFFFF)
FROM   (SELECT ',' + t.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(128)')
        FROM   (SELECT (SELECT *
                        FROM   YourTable
                        FOR XML RAW, TYPE) AS x)v
               CROSS APPLY v.x.nodes('row/@*') AS t(c)
        ORDER  BY t.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(128)')
        FOR XML PATH('')) CA(concatenated)
```

Comment: if  the answer needed in a single row and single column ,then?

Comment:   Add [support for numbers ordering](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8fcb3/1/0) and it will work perfectly ;)

Comment: @lad2025 - The question asks for "sorted alphabetically" - `ORDER  BY t.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(128)')` will order by the value converted to a string. Just change the datatype there if the values are *all* numeric.

Answer (score 0):

given information is not sufficient.In fact that is the not the way to ask question.You have just ask part of question where you are struck.
In this case you get solution also without logic.give the whole scenario.

why you are looking for that output ?

try this,

```
declare @t table(col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50),
col3 varchar(50),col4 varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('1',   '2' , '3'  , '4')
,('A' ,         'B'  ,         'C'   ,      'D')
,('E'  ,        'F'   ,        'G'    ,     'H')
,('I'   ,       'J'    ,       'K'     ,    'L')



select col1 from @t where col1='1'
union all
select col1+','+col2+','+col3+','+col4
from @t
where col1<>'1'
```